# Realm invalidated error even if invalidated == false

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I know that Realm can crash easily with invalidated object... however, I try to catch such state before pursuing with a given object and it usually works.
However, for my Request object sometimes I get a crash on realm.add(self) with "Adding a deleted or invalidated object to a Realm is not permitted".

I am not sure whether invalidated is a false negative or if my "custom" way of verifying an object has been deleted is wrong (I'm just adding the id of the object in a shared dictionary before actually deleting it).

I am a bit stuck on that one and it causes crashes in my app :(

```
if self.invalidated == false{
     if let deleted = RequestHelper.sharedHelper.deletedRequests[id] where deleted == true{
          return
      }
      let realm = try! Realm()
      do{
        try realm.write{
            realm.add(self)
         }
        }catch{}
        id = self.id
    }
    else{
        print("realm invalidation")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about the logic you're using here. You use `realm.add()` to add a new object to a `Realm` instance for the first time. Before then, checking if it's `invalidated` before that will most likely always return false because it shouldn't be backed by a `Realm` at that point yet.

If it's already backed by a Realm instance, it's also important to note that Realm write transactions happen sequentially. Only one may be open at a time, and each one after that will wait until the current one has finished. That being the case, it's feasible that `self.invalidated` was indeed false, but by the time you've opened the write transaction here, another write transaction may have just deleted it.

My recommendation would be to try and rely on Realm itself as much as possible for checking the deleted state of objects instead of relying on a custom mechanism. If `id` has been set as a primary key, you can use `realm.objectForPrimaryKey(ObjectType.self, key: id)` to very quickly check if it already exists in the `Realm` instance or not (Instead of trying to manage a separate list yourself).

Please let me know if you need any extra clarification.